# ¿Como puedo quitar el scroll horizontal en el grid de Genexus?

Tags: genexus

trabajo con GNX 16 u11, cree una clase nueva para grid y en Custom properties tengo overflow-x:hidden pero sigue apareciendo la barra inferior de scrooll

Comment: ¿Qué versión y generador estás usando? ¿Utillizas algun pattern? Puedes probar agregando max-width: 100%;